# Splitting float

Tags: c#, algorithm, optimization

I have a float = 1.30452F

For my WPF UI, I need to split the float into three parts :

- **Part 1** : 1.30
- **Part 2** : 45
- **Part 3** : 2

A working solution is :

```
float myFloat = 1.30452F;

string part1 = myFloat.ToString("0.00");
string part2 = myFloat.ToString().Substring(4,2);
string part3 = myFloat.ToString().Substring(6);
```

Does anyone has a more **performant** and **elegant** way of splitting a float ?

Comment: If you're interested in decimal values, have you considered using the decimal type instead?

Comment: To be specific - you want the number before the decimal point (how many digits can this by, by the way?), then two significant figures, then everything beyond those two significant figures?

Comment: It will also be : 0.00000 or 0.0000. Float is a good choice for me. I dont need more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slight improvement (though using the same method) would reduce your string operations. I ran your original code 1 million times and did a timer on it and it was ~890ms. This change drops that down to 328ms. A decent improvement.

```
string myString = myFloat.ToString();
string part1 = myString.Substring(0, 4);
string part2 = myString.Substring(4, 2);
string part3 = myString.Substring(6);
```

I assume though that you want more than just the first 4 characters for part1. Here's a math version. This one runs in 31ms instead.

```
float part1 = (int)(myFloat * 100F) / 100F;
int part2 = (int)((myFloat - part1) * 10000F);
int part3 = (int)((myFloat - part1 - (part2 / 10000F)) * 100000);
```

Comment: +1- My first thought was to cast versus string parsing. It would need to be tested to ensure that the multiplication didn't change the actual value (since floating point numbers can vary slightly when operated upon).

Comment: I made sure to only use floats during the math operations prior to casting and I did test with a handful of differing values myself prior to submitting. However, I agree, further testing is warranted. Tests are always good!

Comment: Thanks Andy :) I will keep testing ;)